# How can I dismiss the container view from container view self

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a parent View Controller.

The ParentViewController has a container view, the container view is linking to the GreenContainerViewController.

[image]

Now I want to click the button in the ParentViewController,the

GreenContainerViewController is showing(hidden is NO). It is correct.

But I need click the table cell in the GreenContainerViewController to 
close(hidden is YES) the self(GreenContainerViewController).

I try to add code in GreenContainerViewController.m

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     self.view.hidden = YES;
 }
```

I found the View will hidden. but when I click the show button in the ParentViewController , the container view(GreenContainerViewController) was not show again.

Have anyone can teach me how to fix my code or how to solve the problem?

I had post the simple sample project in the github.
https://github.com/dickfalaDeveloper/iOSContainerViewTestDemo

And I post import part code in here , thank you very much.

In the ParentViewController.m file part code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_containerView.hidden = YES;

 }

 - (IBAction)showContainerAction:(id)sender {
_containerView.hidden = NO;
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 }
```

My purpose is click the button in the parent viewcontroller, that can show the container view controller( Default init is not showing).

Then click table cell in the greenContainerView can close the container view.

Answer (score 0):

try to do
**[view removeFromSuperview];**

Comment: You can't use [self.view removeFromSuperview]; Because it is show again, and if use [self.view removeFromeSuperview]; it is can't click button in the parent viewcontroller again.